# When to delete QNetworkAccessManager pointer?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

This is my code. But I am confused where should I delete `m_networkManager`. I can do that in 
`onRequestCompleted()` slot but the problem is my program calls getData function frequently.

My fear is this case:

1. `getData()` is called.
2. Before `onRequestCompleted()` slot is fired, my
   program calls `getData()` again.
3. `onRequestCompleted()` for the first `getData()` call gets fired.
4. my program deletes m_networkManager which was actually allocated other memory when `getData()` was called second time.

I think this situation can cause crash.

```
void MyApp::getData() {
   QNetworkRequest request;
   request.setUrl(QUrl("http://www.domain.foo"));

   m_networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);   // Instance variable
   connect(m_networkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
           this, SLOT(onRequestCompleted(QNetworkReply *)));

   m_networkManager->get(request);

}

void MyApp::onRequestCompleted(QNetworkReply *reply) {
   QByteArray data = reply->readAll();
   reply->deleteLater();
   //m_networkManager->deleteLater();
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new `QNetworkAccessManager` for each request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you create new `QNetworkAccessManager` instance each time `MyApp::getData()` called, you need to manage to delete the right one in `MyApp::onRequestCompleted()` function. The problem in your code is that you always delete the last created `QNetworkAccessManager` and not the one that caused the slot call. My suggestion is following:

```
void MyApp::getData() {
   [..]
   // Not class member. Will be deleted in the slot.
   QNetworkAccessManager *networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
   connect(m_networkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
           this, SLOT(onRequestCompleted(QNetworkReply *)));
   [..]
}

void MyApp::onRequestCompleted(QNetworkReply *reply) {
   QByteArray data = reply->readAll();
   reply->deleteLater();

   // Delete object whose signal triggered this slot.
   QObject *networkManager = sender();
   networkManager->deleteLater();
}
```

Comment: should i delete networkManager before reply or it doesn't matter?

Comment: @user221458, I think it does not matter.